# Restrict loading two same fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using BottomNavigationView. When I click on an option twice then same fragment also loaded twice. How to prevent loading same fragment?

```
 btnNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_item1:
                   loadFragment(fragmentManager, new HomeFragment(), "Home");
                    break;

                case R.id.action_item2:
                        loadFragment(fragmentManager, new SearchFragment(), "Search");
                     break;

                case R.id.action_item3:
                   loadFragment(fragmentManager, new AccountFragment(), "Account");
                    break;


            }
            return true;
        }
    });

 public static void loadFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Fragment fragment, String tag) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

[image: Here is my screenshot]

Comment: please show some code: how do you process the click event ?

Comment: maybe this can help. https://gist.github.com/rfreedman/5573388

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have added my code...

Comment: Do you want to find a previously added instance of a certain Fragment in the back stack and show it again (instead of creating a new instance and adding it on top of the back stack)?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest approach is tracking current fragment which is displayed at BottomNavigationView:

```
int currentTabSelected;
...
btnNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_item1:
               if(currentTabSelected == R.id.action_item1) return true;
               loadFragment(fragmentManager, new HomeFragment(), "Home");
                break;

            case R.id.action_item2:
                    if(currentTabSelected == R.id.action_item2) return true;
                    loadFragment(fragmentManager, new SearchFragment(), "Search");
                 break;

            case R.id.action_item3:
               if(currentTabSelected == R.id.action_item3) return true;
               loadFragment(fragmentManager, new AccountFragment(), "Account");
                break;


        }
        currentTabSelected = item.getItemId();
        return true;
    }
});
```